# Duplicates in my ExpandableListView Adapter

Tags: android, for-loop, expandablelistview

the problem goes is that everytime I add more than one Child to a GroupItem in my ExpandableListView, the item duplicates itself with the previous child. I have narrowed it down to the  getChild() method in my ExpandableListView (custom) adapter.

The getChild() method looks like this:

```
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

     return rCollection.get(weekData.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);

}
```

Where `rCollection = Map<String, List<Custom>>;`
and `weekData = List<String>`;

How do I change the getChild to return only one item per request so I dont get duplicates? I cannot use a for-loop because if I change the groupPosition and childPosition to Arrays I will have to implement the method again.

To Illustrate, this is what the issue looks like:

[image: Duplicates]

How do I exclude the Item 2 from being picked up by the first time it is called, and how do I exclude item 1 from being called the second time it is called? And so on.

Thank you for reading and all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug it out of some old repo, I think this is what I ended up doing.

```
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // Fixes a bunch of NPE when the groupPosition = NULL. This way it checks and returns 0 when it = null. 
    List<MySQLWeek> group = rCollection.get(weekData.get(groupPosition));

        if (group == null){
        return 0;
        }

        return group.size();


}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public int getChildCount(.....)
{
     return 2;
}
```

If you are sure that **for every item there are only 2 subitems** 
Sorry my bad this is the right method you want. 
 **EDIT**

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
{
    return (rCollection.get(weekdata.get(groupPosition())).size();
}
```

This will return the size (length) of your `List<Custom>` for a map. 
**balance paranthesis if needed**

Comment: The childItems are dynamic, so sometimes it might be two, sometimes it might be 5. Hence, why this method cannot be used. Ive tried. Thanks thought.

Comment: Thanks for trying, Johnthetripp3r. But the method im talking about is getChild, not getChildCount.  I didnt notice that until now.

Comment: @Paul Sorry for my silly mistakes. take a look at it now. I guess this should work fine now.

Comment: @Paul If you have any doubt please ask

Comment: @johnthetripp3r, the problem isnt that the getChildrenCount isnt returning any values. That works well, but why is it that all the values of my Map instead of just one in my getChild? Because everytime I add a new item to the Map, it will then also add another one to the next one added, so there are plenty of duplicates. How do I handle this?

Comment: @Paul, I'm stuck in the same place. Can you post the code that worked?

Comment: @Supradip.M Check below, I dont know if itll help you, the project was closed a long time ago :). Sorry I cant be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

am not sure if you found a solution but here is what worked for me; since i was returning a recyclerview in the child view, just return 1 in getChildrenCount() method.

That's it